# A question about sinc function and integral

Tags: calculus

I have one question as following:
Can we move f(x) out of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)sinc(x)dx$?

If $f(x')\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}sinc(x)dx$=$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)sinc(x)dx$?

Comment: what is x' ?  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is really no reason you could put $f$ out of an integral.

The only case where you can separate integral terms is when the 2 functions inside are decorrelated (e.g., f constant).

Answer (score 0):

No, reason being that f(x) is a function with variable parameter of x. The only way you would be able to do it is if you were told f(x) is a constant value.

Comment: it's a special case. decorelated is the general case. e.g., f = white noise.